# Get resourceId using boto3 library

Tags: aws-api-gateway, boto3

I'm trying to figure out where to pull resourceId of an apigateway using this documentation - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html

I was able to retrieve `restApiId` using the method `get_base_path_mapping()`. There are other boto3 API-Gateway methods that I need to use but it requires `resourceId` as a required parameter. However, I can't find which method returns the resourceId value. I checked `get_resource()` method but looks like it's not the one since it also requires `resourceId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_resources` will do the trick